# How Do You Enumerate Over a List of Strings, Converting Each String to Its Own List?

Tags: python

I know I can use split and variable assignment to convert a string within a list to a separate list, like this:

```
list_of_strings = ["the 1st string", "the 2nd string", "the 3rd string"]

first_list = list_of_strings[0].split(" ")
```

But what I cannot quite figure out how to do is how to do this conversion through enumeration so that I don't have to manually do this for each item in my list.

Comment: Look up what a loop is.

Comment: I know what a list is. Knowing what one is doesn't help me know how to perform the task. Out of curiosity, why did you remove the Python tags?

Comment: 1. I said a _loop_, not a list. 2. The Python tag is the one I _didn't_ remove.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **list comprehension** for this task:

```py
list_of_split_string = [the_string.split(" ") for the_string in list_of_strings]
```

Comment: This would create a new list: list_of_split_string and within that list would be lists of the former strings, converted to embedded (not sure that's the correct word) lists. Right?

I can probably make that work, even though it wasn't what came to mind. I'm sure this is a much more efficient approach... assuming I understand it correctly.

Comment: Instead of embedded, you'd call it a _nested_ list. A list within a list. Yes.

These list comprehensions are just very nice and expressive. They say exactly what sort of list you're building. For example, `squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]` will give a list of all square numbers from 0 to `9**2 = 81`.

Comment: "Nested" gotcha. And that clarification helps. One of the things I'm noticing early on in my development education is that terminology is sort of a double-edged sword. You often need terminology you don't know to properly ask your initial question. You also need it when asking for clarification. And often times, you get lectured for not using the correct terminology from the start, when you really didn't know how and weren't equipped to do so. So, I greatly appreciate the patience and education.

Answer (score 0):

You could use map on your list to apply str.split to all its elements:

```
list(map(str.split,list_of_strings))

[['the', '1st', 'string'], ['the', '2nd', 'string'], ['the', '3rd', 'string']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I  hope this one help:

```
ls = [i.split(",") for i in list_of_strings]
```

**Output**

```
[['the 1st string'], ['the 2nd string'], ['the 3rd string']]
```